# Handling NSError with error.code

Tags: ios, error-handling, conditional-statements, nserror

I am trying to handle specific `NSErrors` with `UIAlertView` but none of the codes in the if statements are called when the webview `didFailLoadWithError` is called. Below is my condition statement:

```
 - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
loadFailedBool = YES;
NSLog(@"Error code %ld", (long)[error code]);
if ([error code] != -999) {
    //loading was cancelled and another one initiated. Don't show alert
    return;
}
else if ([error code] == NSURLErrorTimedOut || [error code] == kCFURLErrorTimedOut) {
    //connection timed out
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Network Connection timed out" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    alert.tag = 1;
}
else if ([error code] == -1005) {
    //connection lost
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Network Connection to the host is lost" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    alert.tag = 1;
}
else if ([error code] == kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet || [error code] == -1009) {
    //no internet connection
    NSLog(@"Error here");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Looks like you are not connected to the internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    alert.tag = 1;
}
else if ([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102) {

    return;
  }
}
```

My question is, how do i get the condition called because the log prints -1009 sometimes  when there is no internet. Thanks

Comment: It is pointless to say `[error code] == kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet || [error code] == -1009`, since `kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` _is_ `-1009`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you will never get past this line:

```
if ([error code] != -999) {
    return;
}
```

So if the error code is `-1009`, or *anything* but `-999`, it's too late - you have already said `return` and the whole thing is over. The later code won't execute.

Comment: You know its time to take a nap when you start making trivial errors. Thanks Matt. I think I need a break.